# How to replace URL protocol using PHP?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, social-sharing

I'm using HTTPS everywhere in my website but I have problems with sharing buttons for Pinterest and Tumblr. For example, when I try to share image on Pinterest I get this error: "Sorry we could not fetch the image."

To make it work, I think I need to change image source URL protocols to HTTP only for my sharing buttons.

This is how I get thumbnail source:

```
$share_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
```

I need to change this: 
**https://** www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/example-image.jpg

to this:
**http://** www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/example-image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `set_url_scheme()` function.

```
$share_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
$share_image_src = set_url_scheme( $share_image_src, 'http' );
```